# Swift Core Data: Linking 2 entities

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, model

This is my model:

[image]

I'm trying to link `Expense` and `Trip`. I want to store a `Trip` and set it as default, so every time I create a new `Expense`, this *default* `Trip` is assigned to it.

My `TripManager` has 2 methods to store and recover the `Trip`:

```
  func setTripAsCurrent(trip: Trip) {
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: trip)
    defaults.set(data, forKey: TRIP)
  }

  func getCurrentTrip() -> Trip? {
    if let data = defaults.object(forKey: TRIP) as? Data {
      let trip = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data)
      return trip as? Trip
    }
    return nil
  }
```

And this is my `ExpenseManager`, where I want to link the trips and expenses:

```
  func addExpense(qt: Double, date: Date, catSelected: String, country: String, note: String) -> Bool {


    //Retrieve the entity that we just created
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Expense", in: context)
    let expense = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)


    //Get values
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
    let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
    let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)


    //Set the entity values
    expense.setValue(qt, forKey: AMOUNT)
    expense.setValue(currencyCode, forKey: CURRENCY)
    expense.setValue(day, forKey: DAY)
    expense.setValue(month, forKey: MONTH)
    expense.setValue(year, forKey: YEAR)
    expense.setValue(catSelected, forKey: CATEGORY)
    expense.setValue(date, forKey: DATE)
    expense.setValue(note, forKey: NOTE)
    expense.setValue(country, forKey: COUNTRY)


    let e = expense as! Expense
    e.trip = tripmanager.getCurrentTrip()!

    //Save the object
    do {
      try context.save()
      NSLog("Expense stored successfuly")
      return true

    } catch let error as NSError {
      NSLog("Could not save \(error)")
      return false
    }

  }
```

The app crashes with the following code:

2017-10-06 16:25:02.887 Travelcash[11518:420994] -[Trip initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000278400
2017-10-06 16:25:02.909 Travelcash[11518:420994] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Trip initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000278400'
*** First throw call stack:
...

Does anyone have any hint on how to do this properly?

Comment: You don’t need the archive/unarchive stuff. You simply set the trip as the property of the expense and core data does the rest. Your trip->expense relationship should be a “to-many” however, as a trip can have multiple expenses. Once you do this, your `trip.expenses` will be a set of expenses related to the trip.

Comment: I archive it because I want it to persist. I did a work around archiving the name of the Trip as a string and then fetching it later. So far it works.

Comment: But that is what Core Data does; it persists data.  I don't see why you would need to use archiving as well

Comment: But if I would like to set one Trip as default trip, how would you store it? Let's say I have trip a, b and c. The user sets trip b as default. The app should add expenses to trip b unless the user sets another trip as the default trip. I wanted to archive the default trip set by the user...

Comment: You would just store the `uriRepresentation` of the [`objectID`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506848-objectid) of the default trip; then you can easily retrieve it using [`managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468882-managedobjectid)

Comment: I'll do it that way. Thanks a lot for the help! 